# Firebase functions shuffle firestore array onUpdate

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to get the `Question Array` which is filled with multiple maps.
This is my Firebase structure:[Firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrtZ3.png)
Then I want to shuffle it with the `shuffle` function and update it in my firestore after.

```
 exports.shuffleSet = functions.firestore
.document('duell/{duell_id}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
  
  const data = snap.data();
  const questionsArr = data.set.question;
  console.log(questionsArr);

  const shuffle = (array) => {
    var currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;
  
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex--;

      [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
        array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
    }
    console.log("Geshuffled: " + array);
    return array;
  }

  return questionsArr.update(shuffle(questionsArr));
});
```

I always get `TypeError: questionsArr.update is not a function` and `Function execution took 22 ms, finished with status: 'error'` in my Logs.

What am I doin wrong?

Comment: Your questionsArr appears to be an array of objects. I don't think js arrays have an "update" method available. I think you are treating that array as if it were a firestore document reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update method is a method of the [`DocumentReference`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html) class. So you have to call it on `snap.ref` as follows:

```
exports.shuffleSet = functions.firestore
    .document('duell/{duell_id}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        const data = snap.data();
        const questionsArr = data.set.question;
        console.log(questionsArr);

        const shuffle = (array) => {
            var currentIndex = array.length, randomIndex;

            while (0 !== currentIndex) {

                randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
                currentIndex--;

                [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
                    array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
            }
            console.log("Geshuffled: " + array);
            return array;
        }

        return snap.ref.update({ shuffle: shuffle(questionsArr) });
    });
```

Comment: Working perfectly. The only thing I had to adjust was the return : `return snap.ref.update({ questions: shuffle(questionsArr) });`

Comment: Hey @kartse, you may also [upvote the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). Thanks.